# Updating Main.storyboard constraints programatically (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, textview, constraints, xcode-storyboard

I want to update the bottom anchor of my textview to a constant equal to the height of the keyboard when it appears so that it doesn't cover the text in the textView. I have a constraint identifier in Main.storyboard set as "bottomTextViewConstraint" for my textView, we well as the following code:

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                    print("This prints")
            for constraint in self.textView.constraints {
                    print("This does not print")
                if constraint.identifier == "bottomTextViewConstraint" {
                    constraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
                    print("This does not print")
                }
            }
            textView.updateConstraints()
        }
    }
}
```

self.textView.constraints is nil... It seems that programatically I can't access what I have set up in the storyboard. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constraint relating the bottom anchor of a text view and its super view's bottom anchor will be added to *the text view's super view*, so you cannot find it in `textView.constraints`.

A much simpler way to do this is to add an IBOutlet from the storyboard:

```
@IBOutlet var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

Right click on your view controller in the storyboard, then connect `bottomConstraint` to the constraint shown in the outline view:

[image]

Then you can remove your entire for loop and replace it with just:

```
bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardSize.height
```